# Past Tense of "does respect"

Tags: past-tense

I want to emphasise the fact that something "does respect" what agreed, but in the past.

Is it

> The file that we sent you yesterday "did respected" what agreed?

or

> The file that we sent you yesterday "did respect" what agreed?

Comment: We don't really use a file to "respect" an "agreement". I think we need to know what you are trying to say. Perhaps 1). we agreed that I would send a file, here it is. Or 2). We have an agreement that some documents we are writing will conform to some structure, or avoid revealing some confidential information. Here is one such document so that you can see we are abiding by the agreement. Tell us a little more about the situation.

Comment: If the agreement hasn't changed, then the file still **does** respect it, even if it is yesterday's file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write,

> The file we sent you yesterday respected our agreement.

Though also acceptable would be:

> The file we sent you yesterday fulfilled our agreement.

Though this implies a sort of finality, like sending the file represented the completion of an obligation that would become irrelevant going forward.

> The file we sent you yesterday was pursuant to our agreement.

This is a distinctly legal-sounding word choice.

> The file we sent you yesterday was respective to our agreement.

This is a bit awkward, but your message would come across.

Finally, if you want to emphasize the respect -- as may be appropriate in a situation where someone was suggesting or stating outright that the letter did *not* respect the agreement -- you could say:

> The file we sent you yesterday did respect our agreement.

You could choose to emphasize the 'did.'

This emphatic form can be seen in another example as:

> The file we sent you yesterday did fulfill our agreement.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your proposed versions of your question.
To answer your actual question, the past tense you are looking for is *did respect*, not **did respected*. You only conjugate one part of the verb, not both.

Furthermore, the order of the words in your question makes it hard to understand. A question is not formed *just* by placing a question mark at the end!

The affirmative sentence would be

> The file that we sent you yesterday respected what (we) agreed.

You *could* emphasize that with:

> The file that we sent you yesterday did respect what (we) agreed.

The question would be

> Did the file that we sent you yesterday respect what (we) agreed?

Now, the affirmative sentence *can* emphasize the respect a bit, but the question can not. That is simply because the verb *do* is always used in a question like this. If you want to, you can emphasize differently, for instance

> Did the file that we sent you yesterday *really* respect what (we) agreed?

**Note** that the general choice of wording is not really natural-sounding. This is explained in some other answers, I focused on the grammatical part in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Between your two options, "did respect" is the correct expression, although the alternatives given in Zach's answer are more common.

If you want to add emphasis, you should consider using the word "indeed" which can fit in ahh of these sentences. For example

> The file we sent you yesterday was *indeed* pursuant to our agreement.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the use of "comply" rather than "respect".

> The file that we sent you yesterday complied with our agreement.

You can then emphasize the verb "comply" as follows:

> The file that we sent you yesterday did comply with our agreement.

Answer (score 0):

> The file we sent you yesterday did respect our agreement.

This sentence is the more correct one. Whenever you use the word "did" the sentence automatically turns into past tense. So we leave the word associated with did, in the the present tense.

> did eat - correct
>
> did ate - wrong

Therefore "did resepced" is wrong. "did respect" is grammatically correct.

As @zach has mentioned, it is good to use alternatives like "fulfill" instead of "respect", because we are addressing a formal communication context.